# Iterate over array argument and insert them

Tags: postgresql

I want to create callable function test_func_from_array(_test_id integer, _test_array text[]). I need to insert data with same test_id, but different elements of array _test_array. _test_array consist of strings that I need to split and insert. I tried to do like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_func_from_array(_test_id integer, _test_array text[])
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
begin
    foreach i in array _test_array
    loop
        INSERT INTO public.test_func_array_trgt ("_test_id",test_from_array_1, test_from_array_2, test_from_array_3)
            VALUES( insplit_part(i, '/', 1), insplit_part(i, '/', 2), insplit_part(i, '/', 3));
    end loop;
END;
$function$
;
```

But it gives me an error  `loop variable of FOREACH must be a known variable or list of variables`. What am I doing wrong?
Is the given approach the right one or should it be done differently?

Upd.

Changed to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_func_from_array(_test_id integer, _test_array text[])
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
    i varchar;
begin
    foreach i in array _test_array
    loop
        INSERT INTO public.test_func_array_trgt (test_id,test_from_array_1, test_from_array_2, test_from_array_3)
            VALUES( "_test_id",split_part(i, '/', 1), split_part(i, '/', 2), split_part(i, '/', 3));
    end loop;
END;
$function$
;
```

Everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Changed to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_func_from_array(_test_id integer, _test_array text[])
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare 
    i varchar;
begin
    foreach i in array _test_array
    loop
        INSERT INTO public.test_func_array_trgt (test_id,test_from_array_1, test_from_array_2, test_from_array_3)
            VALUES( "_test_id",split_part(i, '/', 1), split_part(i, '/', 2), split_part(i, '/', 3));
    end loop;
END;
$function$
;
```

And everything works fine. I needed to declare `'i'` for `'for'` before.